# Creating a Partial View from a Model's list in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

So, i have this class here:

```
public class Platillo
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual String NombrePlatillo { get; set; }
    public virtual int idRestaurante { get; set; }
    public virtual String DescripcionPlatillo { get; set; }
    public virtual bool esAprobado { get; set; }
    public virtual bool esDisponible { get; set; }
    public virtual double precio { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime vigenciaPlatillo { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ListaIngredientes>  listadeIngredientes { get; set;}
}
```

I've created a strongly typed PlatilloController that makes all basic CRUD operations. The problem is, the View renderes everything but the List.
My idea is to create a List that allows to add new ingredients(Ingredientes) and the amount of servings (Porciones) for each one on a dish (Platillo).

```
public class ListaIngredientes
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Ingrediente ingrediente { get; set; }
    public virtual int porciones { get; set; }
}

public class Ingrediente
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual String NombreIngrediente { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

So, what i was thinking was to implement a PartialView that rendered a list of every ingredient on the dish, and that allowed to add new ingredients. How exactly do I do that? And, since i plan on creating and updating new ingredients on the same page, i'm sure i should be taking AJAX into account. How exactly can i use Ajax to Create and display ListaIngrediente's list entries?

Answer (score 1):

Just a sample using a partial view page, try this:

```
@model <Project>.Models.Platillo

@foreach(ListaIngredientes ing in listadeIngredientes)
{
      <div>@ing.ID</div>
      <div>@ing.Ingrediente.NombreIngrediente</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am alittle bit confused about your design why would you use a list  public

`virtual List<ListaIngredientes>  listadeIngredientes { get; set;}` I would start but first creating a Platillo foreign key in your ListaIngredientes that would match with  Platillo something like  PlatilloID so now you would have a list of ListaIngredientes that match the Platilloios and it ingridients.

and then sure you can create an ajax partial view at which you can add Ingrediente and then match specific ingridients with your Platilloio on a separate view in another word create separately ingridiets and Platilloio and then on another view add ingridiets from the ingridients in your Ingridients table to Pelatio.